# Thrift IDL : service response as list contain dict

Tags: python, thrift

i want to get the response of thrift server

the response is `[{'a':'b','c': ['xxx','xxx']},{'a':'b','c': ['xxx','xxx']}]`

i try to write a thrift IDL like this ,but failed

```
struct QcAccount {
    1:string username,
    2:string wangwang,
    3:string true_name,
    4:list<string> shop_list,
}



service RedisOperation {
    list<QcAccount> get_qc_account_shop(1:i64 company_id),
    bool get_redis_manager(1:i64 company_id),
}
```

```
and i got this error-msg:
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiothrift/protocol.py", line 140, in write_val
    for fid in iter(val.thrift_spec):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'thrift_spec'
```

i dont know how to make a right data from thrift-server

Comment: Are you trying to feed the non-Thrift-formatted response data above into a Thrift deserializer?

Comment: finally i change the data to json,and in the thrift client i loads the json-str. its worked in this way.but thanks to u